# Eloquent `update()` method also updates dirty columns

Tags: laravel

I noticed when i use eloquent `update()` method it also updates dirty column:

```php
$user = User::find(1);

$user->is_admin = 1;

$user->update(['first_name' => 'Alex']);

//is_admin updated to 1   !
```

Shouldn't it only update `first_name` column?

**What eloquent method only updates the given fields and ignores dirty columns ?**

Note that I know about `refresh` and `fresh` methods which adds additional query which is not the method I look for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reset the Model attributes to the original one (from the first query or last fresh/refresh) use `syncOriginal()`

It will not work **when used after the update** in this case because when you update using the model instance, it will also update the dirty attribute `is_admin` (check your database).

as the [file definition](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Model.php) shows, it still runs `->save()` on the model and will save the change on the `is_admin` too.

```
/**
     * Update the model in the database.
     *
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @param  array  $options
     * @return bool
     */
    public function update(array $attributes = [], array $options = [])
    {
        if (! $this->exists) {
            return false;
        }

        return $this->fill($attributes)->save($options);
    }
```

The solution would be to ignore the instance and go through a new query

```
$user = User::find(1);

$user->is_admin = 1;

User::whereKey($user->getKey())->update(['first_name' => 'Alex']);

//you should also set it in the model
$user->first_name = 'Alex';
$user->setOriginalAttribute('first_name', 'Alex');
```

Comment: I tested the `syncOriginal()` and its working btw

Comment: @Mwthreex yeah it works, it will reset the attributes the the original ones. but the `update()` will also update all dirty attributes including `is_admin`. The question is about an alternative to the `update()` issue, not the reset. i added it for extra information.

Comment: When i append this after is_admin = 1 , it didnt change the value of it are you sure ?

Comment: @Mwthreex the `is_admin` will return to its original value. if you dont want to keep the change on `is_admin` then just sync before the update. if you want to keep the dirty changes, then use the solution above.

Comment: @Mwthreex i see the confusion, added what i meant in bold in the answer. (when used after the update)

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in method to revert values before updating as far as I know but you can probably make your own:

```
$user = User::find(1);

$user->is_admin = 1;

$user->update(array_merge($user->getOriginal(), ['first_name' => 'Alex']));
```

This should only update `first_name` but might also revert the dirty attributes

Comment: Yes it's working but the `syncOriginal()` also reset all dirty field into original values (NF9S answer)

Comment: @Mwthreex this will work too and it is equivalent to `syncOriginal()` **before** the `update()` as it will get rid of all dirty changes and is_admin will return to the original value.